# Recursively listing directory with Apache pig

Tags: apache-pig

Is there a way to recursively list all files in a specific directory, using only pig embedded functions ? An equivalent would be `ls -R` in *bash*.

There exists a `ls` command, but it doesn't take parameters.

I'm aware it may easily be implemented in java, but would rather avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To recursively list directory in hdfs:
fs -lsr

in local filesystem, you can use sh to run any shell command.

see http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/cmds.html#fs
and http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html

Comment: Is this possible to use this in the java api ?